# Custom Calendar Converter not picking up calendar attributes

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

I have the following JSF:

```
<rich:calendar id="startDate"
                        value="#{myBean.startDate}" defaultTime="00:00"
                        disabled="#{myBean.disabled}"
                        popup="true" required="true" 
                        showWeeksBar="false"
                        dayDisableFunction="isDayEnabled"
                        dayClassFunction="getDisabledStyle"
                        requiredMessage="#{msg.errorStartDateNull}"
                        datePattern="#{myBean.datePattern}"
                        showApplyButton="false" cellWidth="24px" cellHeight="22px" todayControlMode="hidden"
                        style="width:1000px"
                        timeZone="#{myBean.defaultTimeZone}"
                        styleClass="noToday" showFooter="false" converter="calendarConverter" immediate="true">
```

and here is my converter:

```
@FacesConverter("calendarConverter")
public class CalendarConverter extends DateTimeConverter
{
    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value)
    {
        Date calDate = (Date) component.getAttributes().get("currentDate");

        if (calDate instanceof Date) {
            return super.getAsObject(context, component, value);
        }
        else {
            throw new ConverterException(new FacesMessage("Invalid Date Format"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value)
    {
        return super.getAsString(context, component, value);
    }
}
```

I need to check the currentDate attribute on the calendar but it is null when I apply the immediate="true" attribute to my calendar component. If I remove the imediate attribute my converter is never called (JSF seems to be using it's own conversion) and sending it's own error message to the screen:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2012asd"
```

How can I return a custom error message when the currentDate attribute is not a date? (It has been tampered with via tamper date firefox plugin)

### Update

I have provided a constructor to the converter to see if it is going in at all when submitting the form (With immediate=true removed). It is going into the constructor but still not calling my getAsObject method.

```
public CalendarConverter()
{
    super();
}
```

Thanks

Comment: have you tried replacing the convertor attribute by placing <f:converter converterId="calendarConverter"/> in your rich:calendar?

Comment: I have Daniel with no luck, it still displays the java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2012asd" and ignores my converter

Comment: have you looked at this https://community.jboss.org/message/57921 they talked about specific version of richfaces...

Comment: Still no use I'm afraid. I'm using Richfaces 4.0 so this should be fixed anyway.

Comment: have you tried validation through javascript?

Comment: @Luiggi - JavaScript is not an option as users could bypass this.

Answer (score 0):

you can handle the exception by adding the `<error-page>` in web.xml file.

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>java.lang.Exception</exception-type>
    <location>/errorpage.html</location>
</error-page>
```

This will display errorpage.html for any instances of Exception.

More information can be had from this link as well.
 http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B32110_01/web.1013/b25947/web_val.htm

Hope this will help you

Comment: I have small suggestion here is that instead of returning directly from the method by calling super.getAsObject(), validate the date for its format.Also, you may include all code in a try catch and if no exception, then return the date, else throw your own error message.